# Why doesn't pin 19 work when powering the EzSBC Esp32 board from batteries?

Tags: power, esp32, battery

I recently got an [ESP32-01 Breakout and Development Board](https://www.ezsbc.com/index.php/featured-products-list-home-page/wifi01-35.html) from EzSBC.com.  It is advertised as a board specifically designed for use with batteries because of it's low current draw when in sleep.

As a test I loaded the basic Arduino `blink` sketch onto the board using pin 19 as the built in test LED.  When I power the board from the computer through the USB connection the LED blinks as expected, but when I connect a battery accross VIN -> GND nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle design choice in this board that took be hours to figure out.

According the [connection schematic](http://www.ezsbc.com/index.php/productattachments/index/download?id=30) the blue leg of the LS3528RGB LED is connected to `IO19` through a 1k resister (`R2-1`).  However the power leg is connected to `Vusb` *not* `3.3V` like the other RGB LED.  This means that the LED connected to IO19 is only usable when the board is connected through the micro-USB port and not when connected directly to battery.

This can be useful for programmatically reading whether the board is running on battery or USB.

Comment: so the pin works? only the on-board LED is not powered?

Comment: `This can be useful for programmatically reading whether the board is running on battery or USB.` -- also good for saving power when on batteries.

Comment: Juraj, that is correct.  When the USB is plugged in the pin will be pulled high by a 1k resister.  When on battery, it will be an open circuit.